# Sending video over RF

Tags: microcontroller, rf, power-electronics

I need to stream a Full HD 30 fps video from a rocket to a receiver 10km away. I think I'll the H.265 encoding format. Which transciever can handle such high datarate and speeds. I know this is super hard, but I need to do it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Questions seeking recommendations for a particular product to use are unfortunately off-topic on this site. An amateur rocketry / RC aircraft forum might be better suited for your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Which transciever can handle such high datarate and speeds.

Consumer networking gear, whether WiFi or point-to-point links will do it. The rocket needs to be tracked with a high-gain antenna to maintain the link. With WiFi it's relatively simple to set up an open access point and broadcast the video via UDP. It can be picked up by any of the WiFi sniffer tools on the market, as long as there's good enough tracking to maintain the gain needed to keep the channel bandwidth large enough.

You can also use any of the commercial digital video links used in the broadcast industry etc. There are "on-camera" transmitters available that could be made to fit inside a model rocket.